# Inverse function of $x + x^q$ with rational $q$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inverse, inverse-function

Consider the function:

$$
f_{q}\left(x\right)=x+x^{q}
$$

where $q\in\mathbb{Q},q>0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x\geq 0$.

I am wondering what would be a method for inverting this function. It is monotone increasing on the non-negative reals as far as I see and so should be invertible.

Is there a closed form for the inverse function?
Otherwise, could we express it as a series or an integral perhaps?

Thank you

Comment: It'n not something that you can do in general.

Comment: Of course you can do it in general. [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) If $q=a/b$ with $(a,b)=1$ replace $x$ with $X^b$. The equation becomes $y=X^b+X^a$. Then you can expand $X$ as a Puiseux series.

Comment: See the introduction of ... https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf

Comment: For $q=a/b,a\le5,b\le5$, and $(a,b)=1$, the inverse can be explicitly written using regular radicals and Bring radicals.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem):

$$x^q+x=a\implies x=a+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}a^{qn}}{da^{n-1}}$$

and evaluating with [factorial power $u^{(v)}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorialPower.html):

$$a+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}a^{qn}}{da^{n-1}} = a+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}(qn)^{(n-1)}a^{(q-1)n+1}= a+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n a^{(q-1)n+1}(qn)!}{((q-1)n+1)!n!} $$

[**Test the formula**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x-%280.3-x%5E%2811%2F3%29%29%2Cx%3D+a%2Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5En%2Fn%21+a%5E%281+%2B+n+%28-1+%2B+11%2F3%29%29+factorialpower%28%28n+11%2F3%29%2C+-1+%2B+n%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C15%7D%5D%2Ca%3D0.3) and look at “Substitution”

For $q\in\Bbb N$ there is a [**pattern**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%2Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5En%2Fn%21+a%5E%281+%2B+n+%28-1+%2B+8%29%29+factorialpower%28%28n+8%29%2C+-1+%2B+n%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfty%7D%5D) with [the hypergeometric function $_u\text F_v(…)$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html):

$$\boxed{x^q+x=a\implies x=a\,_{q-1}\text F_{q-2}\left(\frac1q,\dots,1-\frac1q;\frac{2}{q-1},\dots,\frac{q+1}{q-1};-\frac{q^qa^{q-1}}{(q-1)^{q-1}}\right),|a|\le(q-1)q^\frac q{1-q}}$$

I wonder if $q\in\Bbb Q$ is expressible in terms of the hypergeometric function?

Comment: It is related to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463894/how-to-solve-xy-ax-b/4464966#4464966)