# How to solve $x^y = ax-b$

Tags: logarithms, closed-form, inverse-function, transcendental-equations, transcendental-functions

I have encountered this equation:

$$x^y = ax-b$$

I know to find $y$ as a function of $x$ then:

$$y\ln(x) = \ln(ax-b)$$

$$y = \frac{\ln(ax-b)}{\ln(x)}$$

or

$$y = \log_x(ax-b)$$

But the problem I need to find $x$ as a function of $y$ and don't know how .

Comment: Source of the problem?

Comment: Also, x should be greater than 0 so that $x^y$ is well defined right?

Comment: There is no elementary solution, but it can be solved via the Lambert W function and can also be expressed as a series via the Lagrange inversion theorem. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Example).

Comment: @KStarGamer: Lambert $W$ will not help because there is no $x$ in the exponent.  Similar to why $W$ is useless when solving quintic equations in the case $y=5$.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts ah indeed my mistake. The series solution I mentioned is valid however.

Comment: @KStarGamer: That series only works for integral $y$, or is it generic and also wors for, say $y=\pi$?

Comment: @Devansh Bhardwaj , the equation is composited by me to solve a problem , y is the number of terms at a geometric sequence , x is the factor , this equation meant to find x using y at any given geometric sequence sum , Ex if the geometric sequence sum is 1000 , the equation will be x^y = 1000x-999 , at sequence sum 10 x^y = 10x-9 , my practical example was that I have programmed a DCA Martingale bot simulator at excel , y is the number of safety orders , x is the volume scaling , the seq. Sum is the number of shares , I thought there is a simple solution but I was so wrong :D

Comment: To be specific this equation is not a part of the simulation itself , but This equation was meant to help me fast limiting the number of assumptions before running the monte Carlo simulation .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $y\in \Bbb N$, then the problem is finding roots of a polynomial of degree $y$. This problem has general closed-form representations of roots only for $y\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, for example solutions for [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation), [quadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation), [cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula) and [quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation#Solving_a_quartic_equation) equations for the cases 1, 2, 3 and 4, respectively.

Apart from that, there are only few cases that can be reduced to the solutions above:

- $y\in\{-1,-2,-3\}$: Multiply the equation with $x^{-y}$ will result in solving a polynomial equation of degree $y+1$.  Notice that $x=0$ needs special treatment.
- $y\in\{\frac12,\frac13,\frac14\}$: Substituting $x=z^{1/y}$ will yield a polynomial of degree $1/y$ in $z$.
- $y\in\{-\frac12,-\frac13\}$: Substituting $x=z^{-1/y}$ will get us to a polynomial of degree $1-1/y\in{3,4}$.

---

### Approximating Solutions

Apart from that, there are numerical methods like [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) iteration that converge very quickly (quadratically) in the general case:

Approximating zeros of $f(x) = x^y-ax+b=0$ by picking some initial value and then iterating

$$x\mapsto x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}
= x-\frac{x^y-ax+b}{yx^{y-1}-a}
= \frac{(y-1)x^y-b}{yx^{y-1}-a}
$$

---

### How solutions change with (small) changes in $y$

The closest you can get to finding $x$ as a function of $y$, is using the implicit function theorem around a solution of the equation.  So let $g(x,y) = x^y-ax+b = 0$ then the total differential is

$$(yx^{y-1}-a)dx + x^y\ln x \,dy = 0$$

so that

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{x^y\ln x}{a-yx^{y-1}}=:h(x,y)$$

This means that if you found a solution $g(x_0,y_0) = 0$, and you change $y$ a little bit to $y_0+\Delta y$, then the adjusted solution for $x_0$ is around

$$x_0+\Delta x \approx x_0 + \Delta y\frac{x_0^{y_0}\ln x_0}{a-y_0x_0^{y_0-1}}
=\Delta y\cdot h(x_0,y_0)
$$

This is only a hint for $x>0$ (so that we can take $\ln x$) and where the denominator of $h$ is not zero.

---

### Example

Say we have $a=2$ and $b=-4$, then $(x,y) = (2,3)$ is a solution to $g(x,y)=0$.  We want to estimate $x$ when we change $y$ slighly to $y+\Delta y=3.01$. The estimate above tells us we have to expect $x+\Delta x\approx 1.9944548$ whereas the actual solution is around $1.9944853$.

Comment: Thank you so so much for your effort and time , its so helpful and informative , I didn't think that solving this equation is so hard like that , as this equation is composited by me not from a textbook ,I was trying to solve a problem while making a simulation that I need at excel , I thought solving this equation without solver will help me alot , I didn't know its so complicated and indirect like that , thank you again .

Answer (score 2):

Here are $2$ solutions using Wolfram Alpha with a similar derivation to [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326984/is-there-an-analytic-solution-for-xr-x-a-0/4327024#4327024). The function used is [**Inverse Beta Regularized $\text I^{-1}_s(a,b)$**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseBetaRegularized.html) which is usually a [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function). To use it, one must have $0\le s\le 1;a,b>0$:

$$x^y-ax+b=0\implies x=\frac{by\,\text I^{-1}_{-\frac{b^{y-1}(1-y)^{1-y}y^y}{(-a)^y}}(-y,2)}{a(y-1)},y<0,0\le -\frac{b^{y-1}(1-y)^{1-y}y^y}{(-a)^y} \le 1$$

Test the left formula [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5Ey-ax%2Bb%2Cx%3D%28b+y+InverseBetaRegularized%28%28-a%29%5E%28-y%29+b%5E%28-1+%2B+y%29+%28-1+%2B+1%2Fy%29%5E%28-y%29+%28-1+%2B+y%29%2C+-y%2C+2%29%29%2F%28a+%28-1+%2B+y%29%29%2Cy%3D-3%2Ca%3D-9%2Cb%3D10)

and

$$x^y-ax+b=0\implies x=\frac{by}{a(y-1)\text I^{-1}_\frac{b^{y-1}(y-1)}{(-a)^y\left(\frac1y-1\right)^y}(y-1,2)},y>1,0< \frac{b^{y-1}(y-1)}{(-a)^y\left(\frac1y-1\right)^y} <1$$

Test this formula [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5Ey-ax%2Bb%2Cx%3D%28b+y%29%2F%28a+%28-1+%2B+y%29+InverseBetaRegularized%28%28-a%29%5E%28-y%29+b%5E%28-1+%2B+y%29+%28-1+%2B+1%2Fy%29%5E%28-y%29+%28-1+%2B+y%29%2C+-1+%2B+y%2C+2%29%29%2Cy%3D5%2Ca%3D9%2Cb%3D2). For $0<y<1$, try the substitution of $x\to x^{\frac1y}$ and cancel powers.

The question’s creator also mentioned excel in a comment, so try using the BETA.INV function instead of InverseBetaRegularized

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$y=-\frac{\ln(ax-b)+2k\pi i}{\ln(x)}.$$

The function $x\mapsto -\frac{\ln(ax-b)+2k\pi i}{\ln(x)}$ doesn't have a [partial inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) that is an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).
It's an open question if the equation has solutions that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).
$\ $

$$x^y=ax-b$$

$$x^y-ax+b=0$$

$$e^{\ln(x)y}-ax+b=0$$

[LambertW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) cannot be applied either.
$\ $

$$x^y=ax-b$$

For rational $y$, this equation is related to an algebraic equation and we can use the known solution formulas and methods for algebraic equations.
For rational $y\neq 0,1$, the equation is related to a [trinomial equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial).
For real or complex $y\neq 0,1$, the equation is in a form similar to a trinomial equation. A closed-form solution can be obtained using confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ therefore.
$\ $

[Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

[Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)