# Factor $a x^n + b x + c = 0$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I wish to factor the polynomial equation

$$a x^n + b x + c = 0$$

When $a = b$ and $n=5$, we have the Bring-Jerrard normal form of the quintic $x^5 + x + c = 0$. Using the Lagrange Inversion theorem, I could calculate a series solution for $x$, which is exactly the way that Bring radicals were developed. Is there any alternative formulation based solely on algebraic approaches, or is a convergent series easiest?

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463894/how-to-solve-xy-ax-b/4464966) is similar since it asks for the roots of a general trinomial, which help factor it

Comment: Do you want to factor this expression over $\mathbb Q$ or just calculate the roots ? In general, there won't be a solution by radicals.