# Inverse of $\frac{\log(a-x)}{\log(x)}$

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function, inverse-function

I was working with a series, and found that my problem include this function

---

$f(x)=\dfrac{\log(a-x)}{\log(x)}$?

---

Does anyone know what the inverse of this function is?

Answer (score 1):

To get to a different representation, multiply by $\ln x$:

$$y=\frac{\ln(a-x)}{\ln x}$$
becomes
$$y\ln x=\ln(a-x)$$
then apply $\exp$ at both sides
$$x^y=\exp(y\ln x)=a-x$$

So you want to determine $x$ in terms of $y$ and $a$.  For example, if $y>1$ is an integer, then you want roots of a polynomial of degree $y$. There is no closed form for this, and non-integral $y$ don't improve the situation.

There is question [How to solve $x^y =ax-b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4463894/746312) which is basically the same problem$^1$ and some analysis in the answer.  And there is no closed or simple solution either, of course.

---

$^1$Just use that other question with $a=-1$ and $b=-a$.